# Scope in Javascript: Why is the answer 10, not 20?

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm learning about scope in JS. I was just thinking that I'm getting the hang of it, when I came across this example:

```
var x = 20;

for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
}

// returns 10    
console.log(x);
```

Why 10? I would have expected 20 as an answer.

Comment: you are using the same variable in for loop.

Comment: The question is why you would expect 20, you're changing `x` in the loop, and you stop looping when it hits 10 ?

Comment: @adeneo I would expect 10 because I would expect the console.log to pick the variable x that is defined globally.

Comment: You only have one variable `x`, it's the same one you use in the loop. Javascripts variables has function scope, and you need a new function to define a new `x`

Answer (score 1):

When you start your for loop, you are currently writing `for (x = 0)`. This is overwriting the `var x = 20` statement, so now x = 0. The loop continues to run as you would expect.
When you use the `var` keyword, you are creating a new variable in that current scope. Because you are not initializing your `for` loop with the `var` keyword, basically, JavaScript looks for an existing variable called `x`. It finds the one you created with `var x = 20` and will overwrite the reference, so now `x = 0`.

Comment: Awesome. That's helpful. I get now that the loop is executed and then x = 10. However, I still don't understand why the (locally) defined variable overrides the globally defined variable. Let's say my loop wasn't a loop but a function with a locally defined variable x (of whatever value), the result would be "20" (the global variable).

Comment: What Matías Fidemraizer said is correct. The issue is the for loop doesn't create its own scope.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript (EMCA-Script < 6) you can only create *scopes* with functions. Any other language construct won't create scope:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}

// Logs 10 because "i" in the for loop doesn't create
// a block scope so "i" is available after the whole loop
console.log(i);
```

Since you've already declared an `x` before your `for` loop, and the whole loop uses `x` from `0` to `10`, because `for` block won't create a *scope*, it's absolutely right that you get `10`.

### Scopes with functions:

```
function doStuff() {
   // Inner scope
   var a = 10;
}

// Outer scope
var a = 20;
```

Comment: Ahhhhh. That's where my confusion came from. I though same rules apply for a loop than a function. Thanks.

Comment: @snailspeed No problem, I'm glad you solved your concern ;)

Answer (score 0):

It returned 10 because for loop changed it by incrementing. You didn't create new variable, so Javascript automatically overwrote already existing. This is because you created for loop, which has that variable as an initial expression. It happens when you want refer to a variable, that doesn't exist in lexical environment, syntax parser take it from outside. It means in this case, that from global object where you declared variable `x`. Then your loop changed that variable to 10.

I hope, I explained to you what happened. Please be understanding for me, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is 20 at start and then you change its value in a `for` cycle. The cycle changes its value to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. At the end you have 10 as value, so the result you experienced is in fact the expected result.